# Android studio doesn't install on remix OS emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to install an App on remix OS but android studio doesn't show me in the available devices list.
But in the troubleshoot it show me the emulator.

**Found 1 Android device(s) ready for debugging:
Remix_OS [emulator-5554]**

Please help me.
Thanks